# Multiple-readers, single-writer locks in Boost

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, mutex

I'm trying to implement the following code in a multithreading scenario:

```
Get shared access to mutex
Read data structure
If necessary:
   Get exclusive access to mutex
   Update data structure
   Release exclusive lock
Release shared lock
```

Boost threads has a `shared_mutex` class which was designed for a multiple-readers, single-writer model. There are several stackoverflow questions regarding this class. However, I'm not sure it fits the scenario above where *any* reader may become a writer. The documentation states:

> The UpgradeLockable concept is a
>   refinement of the SharedLockable
>   concept that allows for upgradable
>   ownership as well as shared ownership
>   and exclusive ownership. This is an
>   extension to the multiple-reader /
>   single-write model provided by the
>   SharedLockable concept: a **single**
>   thread may have upgradable ownership
>   at the same time as others have shared
>   ownership.

From the word "single" I suspect that only one thread may hold an upgradable lock. The others only hold a shared lock which *can't* be upgraded to an exclusive lock.

Do you know if `boost::shared_lock` is useful in this situation (any reader may become a writer), or if there's any other way to achieve this?

Comment: What is your definition 'exclusive access' if it isn't 'only one thread may hold the lock at a time'? or are you confusing 'one thread at a time' with 'one specific thread chosen in advance'?

Comment: @Pete: I want one thread (*not* chosen in advance) to hold the exclusive lock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`boost::shared_lock` doesn't help in this situation (multiple readers that can become writers), since only a single thread may own an upgradable lock. This is both implied by the quote from the documentation in the question, and by looking at the code (thread\win32\shared_mutex.hpp). If a thread tries to acquire an upgradable lock while another thread holds one, it will wait for the other thread.

I settled on using a regular lock for all reader/writers, which is OK in my case since the critical section is short.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, you can do exactly what you want as shown in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989795).  A call to upgrade to exclusive access will block until all readers are done.

```
boost::shared_mutex _access;
void reader()
{
  // get shared access
  boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(_access);

  // now we have shared access
}

void writer()
{
  // get upgradable access
  boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(_access);

  // get exclusive access
  boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> uniqueLock(lock);
  // now we have exclusive access
}
```

Comment: More than one thread can *use* it, but only one can *hold it exclusively* at any time. Multiple concurrent readers are fine, provided there is no current writer. That is what you want, I imagine?

Comment: And how do I unlock it then?

Comment: probably it unlocks itself at the end of scope.

Answer (score 4):

You know [LightweightLock](http://www.agileprogrammer.com/dotnetguy/archive/2001/12/10/4485.aspx)
or same at [LightweightLock_zip](http://www.agileprogrammer.com/uploads/bradwils/LightweightLock.zip)
does exactly what you want.
I have used it a long time.

[EDIT]
here's the source:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  Copyright (C) 1995-2002 Brad Wilson
//
//  This material is provided "as is", with absolutely no warranty
//  expressed or implied. Any use is at your own risk. Permission to
//  use or copy this software for any purpose is hereby granted without
//  fee, provided the above notices are retained on all copies.
//  Permission to modify the code and to distribute modified code is
//  granted, provided the above notices are retained, and a notice that
//  the code was modified is included with the above copyright notice.
//
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  This lightweight lock class was adapted from samples and ideas that
//  were put across the ATL mailing list. It is a non-starving, kernel-
//  free lock that does not order writer requests. It is optimized for
//  use with resources that can take multiple simultaneous reads,
//  particularly when writing is only an occasional task.
//
//  Multiple readers may acquire the lock without any interference with
//  one another. As soon as a writer requests the lock, additional
//  readers will spin. When the pre-writer readers have all given up
//  control of the lock, the writer will obtain it. After the writer
//  has rescinded control, the additional readers will gain access
//  to the locked resource.
//
//  This class is very lightweight. It does not use any kernel objects.
//  It is designed for rapid access to resources without requiring
//  code to undergo process and ring changes. Because the "spin"
//  method for this lock is "Sleep(0)", it is a good idea to keep
//  the lock only long enough for short operations; otherwise, CPU
//  will be wasted spinning for the lock. You can change the spin
//  mechanism by #define'ing __LW_LOCK_SPIN before including this
//  header file.
//
//  VERY VERY IMPORTANT: If you have a lock open with read access and
//  attempt to get write access as well, you will deadlock! Always
//  rescind your read access before requesting write access (and,
//  of course, don't rely on any read information across this).
//
//  This lock works in a single process only. It cannot be used, as is,
//  for cross-process synchronization. To do that, you should convert
//  this lock to using a semaphore and mutex, or use shared memory to
//  avoid kernel objects.
//
//  POTENTIAL FUTURE UPGRADES:
//
//  You may consider writing a completely different "debug" version of
//  this class that sacrifices performance for safety, by catching
//  potential deadlock situations, potential "unlock from the wrong
//  thread" situations, etc. Also, of course, it's virtually mandatory
//  that you should consider testing on an SMP box.
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#pragma once

#ifndef _INC_CRTDBG
#include 
#endif

#ifndef _WINDOWS_
#include 
#endif

#ifndef __LW_LOCK_SPIN
#define __LW_LOCK_SPIN Sleep(0)
#endif


    class LightweightLock
    {
    //  Interface

    public:
        //  Constructor

        LightweightLock()
        {
            m_ReaderCount = 0;
            m_WriterCount = 0;
        }

        //  Destructor

        ~LightweightLock()
        {
            _ASSERTE( m_ReaderCount == 0 );
            _ASSERTE( m_WriterCount == 0 );
        }

        //  Reader lock acquisition and release

        void LockForReading()
        {
            while( 1 )
            {
                //  If there's a writer already, spin without unnecessarily
                //  interlocking the CPUs

                if( m_WriterCount != 0 )
                {
                    __LW_LOCK_SPIN;
                    continue;
                }

                //  Add to the readers list

                InterlockedIncrement((long*) &m_ReaderCount );

                //  Check for writers again (we may have been pre-empted). If
                //  there are no writers writing or waiting, then we're done.

                if( m_WriterCount == 0 )
                    break;

                //  Remove from the readers list, spin, try again

                InterlockedDecrement((long*) &m_ReaderCount );
                __LW_LOCK_SPIN;
            }
        }

        void UnlockForReading()
        {
            InterlockedDecrement((long*) &m_ReaderCount );
        }

        //  Writer lock acquisition and release

        void LockForWriting()
        {
            //  See if we can become the writer (expensive, because it inter-
            //  locks the CPUs, so writing should be an infrequent process)

            while( InterlockedExchange((long*) &m_WriterCount, 1 ) == 1 )
            {
                __LW_LOCK_SPIN;
            }

            //  Now we're the writer, but there may be outstanding readers.
            //  Spin until there aren't any more; new readers will wait now
            //  that we're the writer.

            while( m_ReaderCount != 0 )
            {
                __LW_LOCK_SPIN;
            }
        }

        void UnlockForWriting()
        {
            m_WriterCount = 0;
        }

        long GetReaderCount() { return m_ReaderCount; };
        long GetWriterConut() { return m_WriterCount; };

    //  Implementation

    private:
        long volatile m_ReaderCount;
        long volatile m_WriterCount;
    };
```

Comment: Broken links. And it sounds like a .net library while I'm looking for a C++ solution (added tag).

Comment: Just a note, above code is unfair and there is situations where threads will never get access and wait forever..

Comment: This never happened in the time I'm using this implementation. It's been seven years and the code runs more than 10 million times a day. Simple and very good.