# boost::shared_mutex multiple-reader / single-writer mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, mutex, boost-thread

I am trying to use boost::shared_mutex to implement a multiple-reader / single-writer mutex. My question is fairly simple, is it possible for a thread to gain reader access to a shared_mutex, when another thread tries to lock that shared_mutex for writing? For example, I have 10 threads, only one of them can write,

- thread 1 has a shared_lock on that shared_mutex and tries to read
  something
- thread 2 has a shared_lock on that shared_mutex and tries to read
  something
- **thread 3 has a unique_lock on that shared_mutex and tries to write something**
- thread 4 has a shared_lock on that shared_mutex and tries to read
  something
- thread 5 has a shared_lock on that shared_mutex and tries to read
  something

The shared_mutex is currently shared locked by **thread 2**, my question is whether it is possible that **thread 4** can gain read access to that shared_mutex, before **thread 3** can write? Is it possible for a reader/writer mutex ever gets into a starvation situation, e.g., 100 reader v.s. 1 writer?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203467/multiple-readers-single-writer-locks-in-boost

Comment: and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/989795/example-for-boost-shared-mutex-multiple-reads-one-write

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the `boost::shared_mutex` leaves the fairness policy up to the implementation. It can be either fair, reader-over-writer or writer-over-reader so depending on which it is for your particular version it's possible that the writer can be starved.

Comment: Tudor, can you tell me bit more more about "reader-over-writer" and "writer-over-reader"? Thanks.

Comment: reader-over-writer means that readers waiting to do `shared_lock` will have priority over writers waiting to do `lock`. writer-over-reader is the opposite.

Comment: When you say "`boost::shared_mutex` leaves the faireness policy up to the implementation" you probably meant to say that `boost::shared_lock` (and friends) leaves the fairness policy to the mutex implementation - `boost::shared_mutex` implements "reader-over-writer" policy (AFAIU). Is there a boost implementation for "writer-over-reader" mutex policy, or do I have to implement my own?