# Multiple-Reader, Single-Writer Lock in Boost WITH Writer Block

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, mutex

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205512/130427) *almost* does what I want.

I want a read-write lock that will:

1. Allow readers to take the lock as long as there is no writer
2. If a writer tries the lock, block out new readers from taking it but allow old readers to finish before giving the writer the lock
3. Once the writer releases the lock, allow new readers

The implementation above does not meet criteria (2). It allows new readers to grab the lock and block out the writer until they are finished.

Comment: What about existing readers when a writer takes the lock?

Comment: They keep it. As said in (2), it should only block _new_ readers.

Comment: That doesn't really sound like a viable locking system :)

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: Existing readers will potentially encounter inconsistent state  if new writers can modify it underneath them.

Comment: They are locked out when they try the lock, so nothing will be changed until the writer is finished. They won't be able to read data while it is being modified.

Comment: "allow old readers to finish before giving the writer the lock" was the missing piece of the puzzle :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. I needed `unique_lock` instead of `upgrade_to_unique_lock`:

```
boost::shared_mutex _access;
void reader()
{
    // get shared access
    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(_access);
}

void writer()
{
    // wait for old shared access readers to finish
    // but block out new shared access readers
    boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> uniqueLock(_access);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But here your "writer" method does not have a "lock" attribute. Do you mean that before the "unique_lock" you still need to do the "upgrade_lock"? Something like:

```
void writer()
{
    // get upgradable access
    boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(_access);

    // get exclusive access
    boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> uniqueLock(lock);
    // now we have exclusive access
}
```

Or did you mix attributes and it should be:

```
void writer()
{
    boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> uniqueLock(_access);
    // now we have exclusive access
}
```